# Why is my code updating an array after the results are displayed rather than before?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this piece of code in my react app and am trying to use it to update the "siblingarray" state in the app.js file based on a prop that was passed into it (category), but for some reason even when the prop.category is updated the array that posts to my console is the previous category's siblingarray.

CategoryList component that should update the sibling array after the new category prop is passed into it from App.js:

```
class CategoryList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      menuClicked: false,
      classes: ["list-item"],
      listitems: [],
      super: 0,
      siblingarray: [],
      setup: 0
    };
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    //test to make sure if update is required

    if (
      (this.state.setup === 0 || this.props.setup === 0) &&
      (this.props.category != prevProps.category || this.state.setup === 0) &&
      this.props.category !== 0
    ) {
      /*this.setState({
          setup:1
      })*/
      axios
        .post("../api/pochecklist.php", {
          category: this.props.category
        })
        .then(res => {
          this.setState(
            {
              listitems: res.data,
              setup: 1
            },
            this.updateSiblingArray()
          );
        });
    }
  }
  updateSiblingArray = () => {
    //console.log("uupdatesublei");
    //console.log(this.state.siblingarray);

    this.state.listitems.map(item => {
      this.setState({
        siblingarray: this.state.siblingarray.concat(item.duplicateid)
      });
      if (Array.isArray(item.sub)) {
        {
          item.sub.map(subitem =>
            this.setState({
              siblingarray: this.state.siblingarray.concat(subitem.duplicateid)
            })
          );
        }
      }
    });
  };
  clickHandler = (sup, id) => {
    if (sup === 0) {
      this.setState({
        super: id
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        super: sup
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    //console.log(this.state.siblingarray);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.listitems.map(item => {
          {
            if (Array.isArray(item.sub)) {
              //console.log(item.sub);
              //console.log(this.state.siblingarray);
              return (
                <div>
                  <ListItem
                    siblingarray={this.state.siblingarray}
                    marked={this.props.marked}
                    menuAdvPrev={this.props.menuAdvPrev}
                    activeItem={this.props.activeItem}
                    menuClick={this.props.menuClick}
                    categoryCollapse={this.clickHandler}
                    key={item.id}
                    id={item.duplicateid}
                    title={item.title}
                    link={item.link}
                    super={item.super}
                    completed={item.completed}
                    currentSuper={this.state.super}
                    category={this.props.category}
                    text={item.description}
                  />
                  {item.sub.map(subitem => (
                    <ListItem
                      siblingarray={this.state.siblingarray}
                      marked={this.props.marked}
                      menuAdvPrev={this.props.menuAdvPrev}
                      activeItem={this.props.activeItem}
                      menuClick={this.props.menuClick}
                      categoryCollapse={this.clickHandler}
                      key={subitem.id}
                      id={subitem.id}
                      title={subitem.title}
                      link={subitem.link}
                      super={subitem.super}
                      completed={subitem.completed}
                      currentSuper={this.state.super}
                      category={this.props.category}
                      text={subitem.description}
                    />
                  ))}
                </div>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <ListItem
                  siblingarray={this.state.siblingarray}
                  marked={this.props.marked}
                  menuAdvPrev={this.props.menuAdvPrev}
                  activeItem={this.props.activeItem}
                  menuClick={this.props.menuClick}
                  categoryCollapse={this.clickHandler}
                  id={item.duplicateid}
                  key={item.id}
                  title={item.title}
                  link={item.link}
                  super={item.super}
                  completed={item.completed}
                  currentSuper={this.state.super}
                  category={this.props.category}
                  text={item.description}
                />
              );
            }
          }
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App.js Code having to do with updating the category:

```
circleClickHandler = (category, name) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        circleClasses: this.state.circleClasses.concat("hidden"),
        listClasses: this.removeClassFromArray(
          this.state.listClasses,
          "hidden"
        ),
        backArrowClasses: [],
        category: category,
        categoryName: ": " + name
      },
      () =>
        this.setState({
          listClasses: this.state.listClasses.concat("clicked"),
          setup: 1
        })
    );
  };
  backClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      menuClicked: 0,
      list: [],
      listClasses: ["hidden"],
      infoClasses: ["hidden"],
      quizInfoClasses: ["hidden"],
      backArrowClasses: ["hidden"],
      category: 0,
      categoryName: "",
      circleClasses: [],
      infoTitle: "",
      infoText: "",
      infoLink: "",
      siblingarray: [],
      activeItem: 0,
      marked: 0,
      setup: 0
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="App">
        <div id="content-wrap">
          <header className="header">
            <div
              id="back-arrow"
              onClick={this.backClickHandler}
              className={this.state.backArrowClasses.join(" ")}
            >
              &larr;
            </div>
            PO Onboarding Checklist{this.state.categoryName}
          </header>
          <div id="sub-header">
            <p>              
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            id="circle-container"
            className={this.state.circleClasses.join(" ")}
          >
            <Circle
              percentage="80"
              category="1"
              circleClick={this.circleClickHandler}
            />
            <Circle
              percentage="60"
              category="2"
              circleClick={this.circleClickHandler}
            />
            <Circle
              percentage="95"
              category="3"
              circleClick={this.circleClickHandler}
            />
            <Circle
              percentage="45"
              category="4"
              circleClick={this.circleClickHandler}
            />
            <Circle
              percentage="12"
              category="5"
              circleClick={this.circleClickHandler}
            />
            <Circle
              percentage="20"
              category="6"
              circleClick={this.circleClickHandler}
            />
            <Circle
              percentage="100"
              category="7"
              circleClick={this.circleClickHandler}
            />
            <Circle
              percentage="26"
              category="8"
              circleClick={this.circleClickHandler}
            />
          </div>
          <div
            id="po-onboarding-list-container"
            className={this.state.listClasses.join(" ")}
          >
            <LearningObjectives
              activeItem={this.props.activeItem}
              menuClick={this.props.menuClick}
              categoryCollapse={this.clickHandler}
              id={0}
              title="Learning Objectives"
              super={0}
              completed={1}
              currentSuper={this.state.super}
              category={this.props.category}
              text={"here are your learning objectives"}
            />
            <CategoryList
              setup={this.state.setup}
              activeItem={this.state.activeItem}
              marked={this.state.marked}
              menuAdvPrev={this.menuAdvanceAndPreviousHandler}
              menuClick={this.menuClickHandler}
              category={this.state.category}
            />
            <Quiz
              activeItem={this.state.activeItem}
              quizClick={this.quizClickHandler}
              categoryCollapse={this.menuClickHandler}
              id={"1"}
              completed={1}
              currentSuper={this.state.super}
              category={this.state.category}
            />
          </div>
          <div
            id="po-onboarding-info-container"
            className={this.state.infoClasses}
          >
            <ListInfo
              id={this.state.activeItem}
              title={this.state.infoTitle}
              info={this.state.infoText}
              onClick={this.menuClickHandler}
              link={this.state.infoLink}
              siblingarray={this.state.siblingarray}
              advanceinfo={this.advanceInfo}
              previousinfo={this.previousInfo}
            />
          </div>
          <div
            id="po-onboarding-quiz-container"
            className={this.state.quizInfoClasses}
          >
            <QuizInfo
              id={this.state.activeItem}
              category={this.state.category}
              onClick={this.menuClickHandler}
              advanceinfo={this.advanceInfo}
              previousinfo={this.previousInfo}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
          <p>Logical Integrations, Inc.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

So basically, as an example, when I click on a circle corresponding to category 1 it should load sibling array:[2,4,5,6,7,8] and it does! But then when I click on the back arrow and select a circle corresponding with category 2, rather than updating the sibling array with the new values, it retains the old ones of [2,4,5,6,7,8]. I have tried to figure out how to fix this for days. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Comparing to `0` with non-strict equality in JS? I see you like to live dangerously.

Comment: @Clarity lol good catch. Those were actually the last lines of code i added as I was trying to troubleshoot said issue... guess in my frustrations I was subconsciously trying to commit programmer suicide :p

Comment: You're calling `this.updateSiblingArray()` instead of passing the reference to `setState`, so it happens before the state changed.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out guys. Well not so much figured out why the problem was occurring but found a way to get around the problem. I basically had to reinitialize the CategoryList component when I clicked the back arrow in App.js. Now it all works! I f anyone could still explain to me why it wasn't working otherwise I would still really appreciate it though. Thank you.